# how to enforce `sort properties` for my json file for every build?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-2019

**Is it possible to sort properties in my json config during pre or post build?**

I have a json file `local.settings.json`:

[image]

Somehow visual studio allows you to automatically sort the properties:

[image]

**Is it possible to sort properties in my json config during pre or post build?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to sort properties in my json config during pre or post
>   build?

I'm afraid the answer is negative. The `Sort Properties` is one [Quick Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/quick-actions?view=vs-2019) which works in development time. While the `pre-build` event is used to do something before the real build process but after development(design or edit) time.

In pre-build event, we can use some dos command like xcopy, we can call .bat file or .exe file, and the event will execute before the build process. For your situation, you may need to call one .exe to sort the properties, but as far as I know, there's no API provided to call the `sort properties` option, so this approach is not accessible for now. Also, now there seems to be no `vs extension` can do this job in build events.

If you do want this feature(one option to control sort properties during build), just let the product team know your idea! You can send your feedback by `Suggest a feature` in [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).Hope it helps:)

Comment: is it possible to do this on save?

Comment: `on save`? Do you mean sort the properties when click the save all button? I think it's a similar situation like in build events.

Comment: The vs extension development way can provide the handler to execute after save-all event I think, but still the original issue, we have no api to call the sort properties in the handler. So I think it's impossible. But if there's related api to call the sort properties, then a pre-build event or custom extension can all work.